# String mutation exercise's solution difference explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm new in coding, I solved a string mutation exercise, it is about you take 2 inputs, a position, and a character, you replace the character in the given position with the new character, I solved it by using this

```
def mutate_string(string, position, character):
    x = list(string)
    x[position] = character
    
    return "".join(x)
```

but I have been told to use this other code which is better, my question why it is better?

```
def mutate_string(string, position, character):
    return string[:position] + character + string[position + 1:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python. Hence you can't replace the character directly. The way you approach the problem requires converting string to list, perform mutation and join the characters back to string (`''.join(x)`, <s>which I do not see in your function</s>). Hence, using string slicing is a cleaner approach with lesser overhead.

Comment: sorry i missed copying the return, there is a return in my code , so the difference is lesser overhead ?

Comment: Yes, there will be a significant latency. For a sample string `a = 'o'*100000000`, you can notice a 20x latency difference.